# How to use default account parameters (login/pwd) in Android phone?

Tags: android

I want to use default user login/pwd in my app.

Do you know how can I have access to this data?

best,
Patrick

Comment: I'm confused.  Which app are you talking about?  Are you programming your own app?  If so, then this question is probably better suited to Stack Overflow instead.

Comment: Thanks for tip. I was refering to my app.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use the Google authentication token in your app, it looks like it is not possible for now.  There is [an open issue on Android](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1073&can=1&q=account%20login&colspec=ID%20Type%20Version%20Security%20Status%20Owner%20Summary) which addresses this problem but it has not been fixed yet.  It looks like there might be one in the future but for now you will just have to ask the user for their username and password.

Comment: Well I'm looking for solution to this problem for 2 days. And it's doable, for now documentations is a problem. Somehow gmail, calendar etc. Are working without prompting user about it :-), so there must be a way.

I posted this problem to Stack Overflow as you suggested. Indeed this is no place for such questions.

Comment: These are Googles own proprietary apps, so yes *they* have a way of doing it, but it's definitely not open to third party devs.